# custom variables in FOR with JsRender

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender, jsviews

I'm migrating from jQuery templates to JsRender and I don't know how to fully translate an `{{each}}` into a `{{for}}`

With jQuery templates I could do something like this:

```
{{each (i, val) object.items}}
    <span data-index="${i}">${val}</span>
{{/each}}
```

Where `object.items` is an array of values and I could define a custom `index` and `item` variables to show data (in this case `i` and `val`). But how do I do the same thing in JsRender?

```
{{for object.items}}
    <span data-index="{{:#index}}">{{:#data}}</span>
{{/for}}
```

I know `index` and `data` are there to show the same thing like jQuery templates, but how can I define custom variables? Is that even possible?

**UPDATE**: The reason for this is to provide some context for the variable that I'm working with. Let me explain with and example (jQuery tmpl)

```
{{each (r, row) object.rows}}
    {{each (c, col) object.cols}}
        //work with both index and item knowing which one is which
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Is this kind of syntax/logic possible with your engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom variable for the data item (equivalent to `val` in the jQuery templates version), as follows:

```
{{for object.items itemVar='~val'}}
    <span>{{:~val}}</span>
{{/for}}
```

There is currently no feature for a custom named `index` variable. (One could imagine adding support using the syntax `{{for object.items itemVar='~val' indexVar='~i'}}` - but that is not currently implemented).

But if your reason for wanting to provide a custom variable for #index is in order to make it available to nested block scopes, you can define a custom variable for `#index` on the nested tag, as follows:

```
{{for object.items itemVar='~val'}}
    {{someNestedTag ~i=#index}}
        <span data-index="{{:~i}}">{{:~val}}</span>
    {{/someNestedTag}}
{{/for}}
```

Now to take the specific case of:

```
{{each (r, row) object.rows}}
    {{each (c, col) object.cols}}
        //work with both index and item knowing which one is which
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is one way to do that in JsRender/JsViews:

```
{{for grid.rows ~grid=grid}}
  {{for ~grid.cols ~rowIndex=#index ~row=#data}}
    Row {{:~rowIndex}} {{:~row.rowProp}}
    Col: {{:#index}} {{:colProp}}
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

If you want to use data-linking, with JsViews, you would instead write the above:

```
{^{for grid.rows ~grid=grid}}
  {^{for ~grid.cols ^~rowIndex=#index ~row=#data}}
    Row {^{:~rowIndex}} {^{:~row.rowProp}}
    Col: {^{:#index}} {^{:colProp}}
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

Note that in the JsViews version, because I want the ~rowIndex to update dynamically through data-binding when preceding rows are removed, I use the syntax `^~rowIndex` - which is an opt-in to data-binding. `~rowIndex` would render correctly initially  but would not update when rows are removed...

You can see it

- here: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/e3ah577p/
- and a similar case for two-dimensional arrays: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/cGZZP/

And out of interest, see also here for grid views using custom tags:

- http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/dg7x8mrc/
- http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/uu7opr3z/

**Additional Note:** In response to the comment below *"why not continue with the {{for (index, item) object}} syntax?"*

In JsRender you can create custom tags very easily, and all tags share a common structure: http://www.jsviews.com/#tags *{{myTag arg0 arg1 namedProp1=xxx namedProp2=yyy}} ... {{/myTag}}* using named parameters (props) and unnamed parameters (args).

So *itemVar='~val'* works for any tag even custom tags (not just *{{for ...}}* ), uses the standard syntax for a named parameter, and allows you to create a contextual template parameter (helper parameter) *val* corresponding to the data item of the template block (or blocks).

Also in JsRender the *(expression)* syntax already has a meaning as an arg. For example, *{{for (1 + 2)}}{{:}}{{/for}}* will output *3*!

In jQuery Templates, there is no support for custom tags, and the *(i, val)* syntax is special-cased for the *{{each}}* tag.

In the common-case scenario you don't need custom variable names and the jQuery Templates syntax:

```
{{each (i, val) object.items}}
    <span data-index="${i}">${val}</span>
{{/each}}
```

is (I would say) slightly more complex than the JsRender one:

```
{{for object.items}}
    <span data-index="{{:#index}}">{{:}}</span>
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Thanks Boris! On a side note, why not continue with the `{{for (index, item) object}}` syntax? I think writing something like `itemVar='~val'` is not as easy as with jQuery templates, not to mention the preceding `~` character .

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clear on what I'm after

Comment: OK - I added to my response for that specific case, and created some jsfiddles illustrating these approaches