# Access parent variable from nested block in JsRender

Tags: key, nested-loops, parent, jsrender

How can I access `props`'s `key` from a nested `for`?

```
{{props object.items}}
    {{:key}}
    {{for prop.other_items}}
        {{:key}} //here I want to print the key from props
```

I've tried:

```
{{:key}}
{{:#key}}
{{:#parent.key}}
{{:#parent.parent.key}}
{{:~root.key}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three alternative ways:

Provide the `key` as a contextual template variable, so it is available in the `{{for}}` block:

```
{{props object.items}}
    {{:key}}
    {{for prop.other_items ~outerKey=key}}
        Outer key: {{:~outerKey}}
   {{/for}}
{{/props}}
```

Provide the data item of the `{{props}}` block (the `{key: ..., prop: ...}` object) as a contextual template variable, so it is available in the `{{for}}` block:

```
{{props object.items itemVar="~outerProp"}}
    {{:key}}
    {{for prop.other_items}}
        Outer key: {{:~outerProp.key}}
    {{/for}}
{{/props}}
```

Step up through the parent views (array view, then props item view) and get the data item (the `{key: ..., prop: ...}` object):

```
{{props object.items}}
    {{:key}}
    {{for prop.other_items}}
        Outer key: {{:#parent.parent.data.key}}
    {{/for}}
{{/props}}
```

And here is a link to a related reply to a previous question from Matias: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362057/1054484