# JsRender If conditions comparing variables between child objects

Tags: jquery, html, jsrender

I am trying to achieve this in JsRender.
As You can see from the code below, SubMenuItems  and SubMenuPages are child objects in a array of objects.However, I would like to compare a value in the first Object with a value in the second respectively.I have only qualified  the if condition just so it is clear what I'm trying to accomplish.

So basically I would like to access an id variable in one child object and then check against  another variable in another object.
I am a bit unsure as to the syntax regarding this , since all i tried kept returning nothing.

```
    {{for SubMenuItems}}
             <li><a href="#">{{>Name}}</a></li> 
             <ul>
                    {{for SubMenuPages}}

                            {{if SubMenuItems.PageMenuId == SubMenuPages.Id }}

                            <li><a href="{{>PageUrl}}" >{{PageName}}</a></li> 


                            {{/if}}


                    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle - in particular to show your actual data structure? Then I will answer, and also update your jsfiddle so it actually works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is `SubMenuItems` an ***array*** of items of which each has a `PageMenuId` - or is it a single object as you seem to say? (And similarly, is `SubMenuPages` an ***array*** of items each of which has an `Id`?)

It is difficult to answer your question without more clarity on your data hierarchy, but basically the documentation here [View Hierarchy](http://www.jsviews.com/#views) - and in particular here [Accessing parent data](http://www.jsviews.com/#views@parent-data) should tell you what you need to know.

If my guess about your data structure is correct, then here is one way you can write your template:

```
...
{{for SubMenuItems itemVar="~SubMenuItem" ~Pages=SubMenuPages}}
  ...
  {{for ~Pages itemVar="~SubMenuPage"}}
    ...
    {{if ~SubMenuItem.PageMenuId == ~SubMenuPage.Id }}
        ...
    {{/if}}
    ...
  {{/for}}
  ...
{{/for}}
...
```

You could also look at these stack overflow questions which are similar to yours:

[Access parent variable from nested block in JsRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395701/access-parent-variable-from-nested-block-in-jsrender/31397325#31397325)

[JsRender. Nested loop by the object of top loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438236/jsrender-nested-loop-by-the-object-of-top-loop/34441881#34441881)

Comment: With regards to your question, you are very correct. SubmenuItems are indeed an array of items  of which each has SubmenuPages which is also an array of items. I hope this clarifies my question. I will try some of the above out and feedback here as well.

Comment: OK - once you have validated, can you also 'accept' the answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa this has been quite a while... whilst the above answer does point in the right direction re: my question , i took a different approach and went for a solution using angularjs.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa. Yes, it unfortunately happens quite often that someone asks a question, and someone else spends time and effort trying to help them with a reply, and then, surprise, the first person doesn't bother to acknowledge or respond. (Even when the response does indeed resolve their question...) It can certainly be discouraging of future efforts to help, which is a shame... Anyway, thanks for taking this up...