# Get array value within jsrender template

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates, jsrender

I have the JSONArray and pass this to jsrender template. How could I get array value within jstemplate.

Array Value

> var clrarr = ["white", "black"]; 
>   var clrcode = ["#fff", "#000"];

Template

```
<select>
     {{for clrarr}}
           <option value="{{>#data}}">{{>clrcode[#index]}}</option>
     {{/for}}
</select>
```

How can I get the `clrcode` value within the jsrender.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of other stackoverflow questions asking how to access "parent data" in JsRender. For example:

- [JsRender If conditions comparing variables between child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119731/jsrender-if-conditions-comparing-variables-between-child-objects)
- [Access parent variable from nested block in JsRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395701/access-parent-variable-from-nested-block-in-jsrender/31397325#31397325)
- [JsRender. Nested loop by the object of top loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438236/jsrender-nested-loop-by-the-object-of-top-loop/34441881#34441881)

Take a look at [Accessing parent data](http://www.jsviews.com/#views@parent-data)

In your case, you can write, for example:

```
<select>
     {{for clrarr}}
           <option value="{{>#data}}">{{>~root.clrcode[#index]}}</option>
     {{/for}}
</select>
```

or

```
<select>
     {{for clrarr ~clrcode=clrcode}}
           <option value="{{>#data}}">{{>~clrcode[#index]}}</option>
     {{/for}}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I refer this section of docs only http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag thats why am posted this question.

Comment: Yes, well you need to read a bit more to understand the range of features of JsRender. Best to research a bit on jsviews.com and here on StackOverflow, before asking for help :). Often your question is already answered...